# How to get the coordinates of a tapped TextSpan?

Tags: flutter

With `GestureDetector`, you can get the size and position of a tapped widget through its `RenderBox`:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
  }
);
```

Because a `TextSpan` is not a `Widget`, calling `context.findRenderObject()` from within a `TextSpan` can only ever give you the box of the widget enclosing `RichText`:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Tap me',
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () {
          //Gets box around RichText, not around this TextSpan
          RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Is there another API to get the coordinates of an individual TextSpan when it is tapped?

Comment: no, there is no such API, you can use `Paragraph` however

Comment: for example [getPositionForOffset](http://localhost/flutter/doc-1.3.2/flutter/dart-ui/Paragraph/getPositionForOffset.html)

Comment: Thanks @pskink, do you know how I could use `Paragraph` within a Flutter `Widget`?

Comment: check [Canvas](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) API

Comment: So it would need to be a [`CustomPainter`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html)... Hmm, it's a shame if there is no way to do this on a higher level

Comment: or custom `RenderBox`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use onTapUp which will give you back tap Information which contains the global touch position.

You can then use that tap information and pass it to the renderObjects globalToLocal conversion function and you'll get a local coordinate inside your widget.

Comment: Thanks, that may end up being the best option. Ideally though I'm looking for the coordinates of the `TextSpan` that is tapped, rather than the coordinates of the tap itself

Comment: Aaah, the render object should help with that. Convert it to a renderBox and use the paintBounds, or any of the other properties to determine where it's placed. You also have the semanticsBounds that you can use

Comment: Exactly, but unfortunately (without being able to place a widget _between_ `RichText` and `TextSpan`) the render box only provides the coordinates of the outer `RichText` widget 

Comment: I see. I see. You'll have to use a workaround then unless you create your own using the current code (it's open source) and then making your additions for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WidgetSpan with Widget child. Then you will get the correct RenderBox in the Widget build.