# How to get the TextPosition in a RichTex from a Gesture callback

Tags: flutter, richtext, hittest

I want to implement in Flutter a popup dictionary. More precisely, I have a **RichText** widget and I want, when the user tap it, to get the text index, the **TextPosition**, corresponding to where the user have tapped to be able to get the surrounding text and process it and then display a popup displaying the definitions of the word found.

But I don't know how to get the TextPosition from a tap position.

From the comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947309/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-a-tapped-textspan), I understand that first I need to have a GestureDetector to define a tap callback. Then from the event argument compute the offset into the coordinates of the corresponding **RenderParagraph** and call  `RenderParagraph.getPositionForOffset()` to get the text position.

But I am a beginner at Flutter and I don't know how I can access the corresponding **RenderParagraph** or whatever object having the wanted information from the tap callack. I got all my dictionary popup system working except for this word detection part.
Can anyone help me with this part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Below code for get text position

```
GestureDetector(
  onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
    // Get the RenderBox of the RichText widget
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

    // Compute the tap position relative to the RichText widget
    Offset localOffset = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

    // Get the RenderObject of the RichText widget and cast it to RenderParagraph
    RenderParagraph renderParagraph = renderBox as RenderParagraph;

    // Get the TextPosition corresponding to the tap position
    TextPosition textPosition =
        renderParagraph.getPositionForOffset(localOffset);

    // Use textPosition to get the surrounding text and process it
    String tappedWord = getTappedWord(renderParagraph.text, textPosition);

    // Display popup dictionary with definitions of tappedWord

  },
  // Your Child Widget
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.
I had to use RenderObject.visitChildren() to get the right renderObject. The paragraph render object was not the one returned by findRenderObject() but once I found the right one it worked perfectly.